# Get the control of AppDomain.CurrentDomain object in application

Tags: c#, .net, logging, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I need to set the current `AppDomain` to what I create.

I want to Log my application exception using Enterprise Library `HandleException` method.  When I handle the exception, it will insert a log into a logging table, and sets the `AppDomainName` field with `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` that is meaningless.

I want to have my own `FriendlyName` for my Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the current application domain.

The [AppDomain.FriendlyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.friendlyname.aspx) property by default has the value of the application file name (Read the remarks section). You cannot change this in the default application domain.

What you can change is the name of your executable assembly. You can change it from your project's properties. Then you can use it like this:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
```

which always returns the name of the process executable assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name remains the same when the executable is renamed. Use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location for the executable file name.